# CloudTable.ExecuteQuery : how to get number of transactions

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

AFAIK the ExecuteQuery handles segmented queries internally. And every request (=call to storage) for a segment counts as a transaction to the storage (I mean billing transaction - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/). Right?
Is there a way to understand in how many segments is splitted a query? If I run a query and I get 5000 items, I can suppose that my query was splitted into 5 segments (due to the limit of 1000 items per segment). But in case of a complex query there is also the timeout of 5 seconds per call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to get at that in the API. You could set up an HTTPS proxy to log the requests, if you just want to check it in development.

If it's really important that you know, use the `BeginExecuteSegmented` and `EndExeceuteSegmented` calls instead. Your code will get a callback for each segment, so you can easily track how many calls there are.